# How to wrap a long literal block in reStructuredText?

Tags: restructuredtext

I have a literal block consisting of a single long line. It is currently displayed as a single-line block with horizontal scrollbar (like the literal block below). How do you implement auto-formatting to wrap the line so it wraps dynamically when the browser is resized?

```
::
  Long line that does not wrap...........................................................................................
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be done by overriding the default CSS with a new style:

```
pre {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

Edit your theme's CSS file to include this directive and it should just work.

Comment: Can't believe it's that simple. Thanks!